# Create xml file to be used in wordpress post import

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, wordpress

Alright here is the thing, I have this site that ***was*** once wordpress but have been converted into **70+ static pages**, the admin is deleted and the whole site is static(which means every page is in index.html), I want to create a script that makes an xml so that I will just have to import it in the new wordpress install.

So far, I am able to create an XML but it **only imports one post**.

The data source is the URL of a page and I use jquery $get to filter only to gather the post of a given archive.

```
//html
<input type="text" class="full_path">
<input type="button" value="Get Data" class="getdata">

//script

$('.getdata').click(function(){
            $.get($('.full_path').val(), function(data) {
              post = $(data).find('div [style*="width:530px;"]');
              $('.result').html(post.html());

            });
        });//get Data
```

Through AJAX I send the cleaned data into a php below that creates the XML:

```
$file = 'newpost.xml';
$post_data = $_REQUEST['post_data'];
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new post to the file
$catStr = '';
if(isset($post_data['categories']) && count($post_data['categories']) > 0){
    foreach($post_data['categories'] as $category) {
        $catStr .= '<category domain="category" nicename="'.$category.'"><![CDATA['.$category.']]></category>';
    }   
}
$tagStr = '';
if(isset($post_data['tags']) && count($post_data['tags']) > 0){
    //populate post_tag like the above
}
$post_name = str_replace(' ','-',$post_data["title"]);
$post_name = str_replace(array('"','/',':','.',',','[',']','“','”'),'',strtolower($post_name));

$post_date = '2011-4-0'.rand(1, 29).''.rand(1, 12).':'.rand(1, 59).':'.rand(1, 59);
$pubTime = rand(1, 12).':'.rand(1, 59).':'.rand(1, 59).' +0000';

$post = '
    <item>
        <title>'.$post_data["title"].'</title>
        <link>'.$post_data["link"].'</link>
        <pubDate>'.$post_data["date"].' '.$pubTime.'</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://localhost/saunders/?p=1</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA['.$post_data["content"].']]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>1</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>'.$post_date.'</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>'.$post_date.'</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>'.$post_name.'</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
        '.$catStr.'
        '.$tagStr.'
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
';



// Write the contents back to the file with the appended post
file_put_contents($file, $current.$post);
```

After being appended I add the code below to complete the xml rss tag

```
</channel>
</rss>
```

If I look and compare the xml file of one that is exported from a wordpress site, I see little difference. Please HELP!!

here is a sample of a generated xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>
<channel>
    <title>lols why</title>
    <link>http://localhost/lols</link>
    <description>Just another WordPress site</description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2012 04:24:04 +0000</pubDate>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.2</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://localhost/lols</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://localhost/lols</wp:base_blog_url>

    <wp:author><wp:author_id>1</wp:author_id><wp:author_login>adedoy</wp:author_login><wp:author_email>wazzup@gmail.com</wp:author_email><wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[adedoy]]></wp:author_display_name><wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_first_name><wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_last_name></wp:author>


    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.4.1</generator>

    <item>
        <title>Sample lift?</title>
        <link>../../breast-lift/delaware-breast-surgery-do-i-need-a-breast-lift/</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2012 9:29:16 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://localhost/lols/?p=1</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>sample</p>]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>1</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>2011-4-0132:45:4</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>2011-4-0132:45:4</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>sample-lift?</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
        <category domain="category" nicename="Sample Lift"><![CDATA[Sample Lift]]></category><category domain="category" nicename="Sample Procedures"><![CDATA[Yeah Procedures]]></category>
        <category domain="post_tag" nicename="delaware"><![CDATA[delaware]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>lalalalalala</title>
        <link>../../administrative-tips-for-surgery/delaware-cosmetic-surgery-a-better-experience/</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 03 Oct 2012 3:20:43 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://localhost/lols/?p=1</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[
                lalalalalala
            ]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>1</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>2011-4-0124:39:30</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>2011-4-0124:39:30</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>lalalalalala</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
        <category domain="category" nicename="lalalalalala"><![CDATA[lalalalalala]]></category>
        <category domain="post_tag" nicename="oink"><![CDATA[oink]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_edit_last</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Please tell me what am I missing....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, to rehash and make sure I understand you, this is an attempt to return to wordpress from your static files.

To do this, there are really three major methods outlined on the WP codex about [importing from an RSS feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Importing_from_an_RSS_feed), [(X)HTML](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Importing_from_.5BX.5DHTML), and [static pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Importing_from_a_Site_of_Static_Pages). This being said, one of the easiest methods if you have well-formed HTML, which it would appear you do from your JQuery search string, is to use the [HTML Import 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/) plugin, referenced in the codex. It provides you a number of options to do this from a directory, url, and to specify the search parameters from the admin screens of your new installation.

Should this not work for you or you really want to convert all the pages to XML for import, because you're already using PHP to generate the XML, I'd strongly recommend using the PHP [DOM](http://us.php.net/dom) library to open, parse, extract, and write the data from your static files. This will save you from the time involved in browsing through the entire site to generate the XML and it will produce an entire XML file of all your pages in one fell swoop.

Either way, I would recommend using a plain RSS file and not trying to re-create WordPress' custom format because, done properly, it has a lot of database references (maps IDs and so forth) for all the content types. Since it doesn't seem you need it, try just making a normal RSS file that has the bare minimum of what you need, and you can edit those posts to re-assign authors, etc. if necessary after you import that using the codex directions for [importing from an RSS feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#Importing_from_an_RSS_feed). It will be far easier.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar case as you. I wanted to generate a xml export file populated with data for post and an featured image.

Here's what I did:

1. Install Wordpress on my localhost
2. Delete the default page and comment setup by Wordpress
3. Modify the post title, content etc (optional, I did it so that it's easier to find those informations in the exported xml file)
4. Install and activate the wordpress importer plugin
5. Export using the tool
6. Look at the xml file

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- generator="WordPress/3.9" created="2014-04-25 14:19" -->
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>

<channel>
    <title>wordpresslocal title</title>
    <link>http://wordpresslocal</link>
    <description>Another Wordpress Local Blog</description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 25 Apr 2014 14:19:36 +0000</pubDate>
    <language>de-DE</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.2</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:base_site_url>http://wordpresslocal</wp:base_site_url>
    <wp:base_blog_url>http://wordpresslocal</wp:base_blog_url>

    <wp:author><wp:author_id>1</wp:author_id><wp:author_login>wordpresslocaladmin</wp:author_login><wp:author_email>wordpresslocal@einrot.com</wp:author_email><wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[wordpresslocaladmin]]></wp:author_display_name><wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_first_name><wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[]]></wp:author_last_name></wp:author>


    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=3.9</generator>

    <item>
                <title>POST TITLE</title>
        <link>http://wordpresslocal/post-title</link>
        <pubDate>Fri, 25 Apr 2014 14:02:29 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[wordpresslocaladmin]]></dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://wordpresslocal/?p=1</guid>
        <description></description>
        <content:encoded><![CDATA[POST CONTENT]]></content:encoded>
        <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[]]></excerpt:encoded>
        <wp:post_id>1</wp:post_id>
        <wp:post_date>2014-04-25 14:02:29</wp:post_date>
        <wp:post_date_gmt>2014-04-25 14:02:29</wp:post_date_gmt>
        <wp:comment_status>open</wp:comment_status>
        <wp:ping_status>open</wp:ping_status>
        <wp:post_name>post-title</wp:post_name>
        <wp:status>publish</wp:status>
        <wp:post_parent>0</wp:post_parent>
        <wp:menu_order>0</wp:menu_order>
        <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
        <wp:post_password></wp:post_password>
        <wp:is_sticky>0</wp:is_sticky>
        <category domain="category" nicename="category1"><![CDATA[CATEGORY1]]></category>
        <category domain="post_tag" nicename="tag1"><![CDATA[TAG1]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[6]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom WordPress export/import XML works actually pretty well with content created from other databases - I've been able to import posts, pages, metadata, attachments, comments etc.

BUT it is indeed rather picky with some elements - like if two posts share same creation time only one is inserted, second post is considered duplicate (so adding random time to date-only source is a must).

In your sample wp:post_date seems to be far from date format, so this could be the reason that triggers duplicate detection, resulting in single post imported.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
<wp:post_id>1</wp:post_id>
```

in both items. I guess this is main problem, because this is primary key.